# Is this method of creating html elements in JavaScript considered outdated?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the newer versions of JavaScript, I know that you have to `createElement()` then you have to `appendChild()` if you wanted to create and html element in JavaScript. However, I stumbled across this method of creating html elements using Jquery and I was wondering if it was outdated?

```js
 $("#options").html("<option value='Millimetre'>Millimetre</option>")
```

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it's outdated, it's that this syntax depends on the jQuery library, and jQuery is still concerned with imperative DOM manipulation. These days, most UI frameworks use declarative patterns because they are easier for developers to author and reason about. Declarative patterns move the complexity closer to the level we can handle, rather than requiring us to move our brains closer to the complexity of the mutation logic.

But we can strip out the jQuery and do basically the same thing:

1. create a string that contains HTML markup
2. inject that string into the document using `.innerHTML`

There are reasons folks don't like working with strings of HTML, which is sometimes called "tag soup":

- there's nothing to protect against basic typos or markup mistakes like nesting errors
- tag soup is hard to read, because even in an editor with intelligent syntax highlighting, the tag soup is just a string, so it will all be one color
- some characters which are valid in HTML need to be escaped inside tag soup, which makes it even harder to read
- long strings of tag soup typically make for very long lines of code; very long lines of code are hard for humans to read, and do not diff well; there are patterns for mitigating this, but that's an extra hassle you have to deal with

That said, there is one really big benefit that tag soup has: better runtime performance. DOM manipulation is typically one of the slowest things javascript does within the browser. I haven't run tests recently, but back in the day a single DOM operation usually took about 100ms. That maybe seems fast, but if you're adding hundreds or thousands of nodes to the document it can add up to several seconds. Setting `innerHTML` is also a DOM operation, but that one operation can create, modify, or remove hundreds or thousands of elements at once. Yes, an `innerHTML` op that adds thousands of elements will probably be slower than an `innerHTML` operation that only adds 5 elements, but it'll probably still be at least one order of magnitude faster than adding each of those elements using individual operations.

Worry less about whether the thing you're doing is "cool" or "cutting-edge." Focus on whether you're using the right tool for the job, whether the tool makes your job easier or harder, whether the tool is reliable across all the platforms and timespans you care about.

It's not your job to please the cool kids. It's your job to write software that does the right thing, for the right reasons, in the most obvious way possible.

Comment: What 100ms per operation? Nhaa even a middle-school calculator would do it faster. Sure setting innerHTML can be faster in some cases than doing a ton of appendChild but each appendChild would never take 100ms. That would mean that for instance ES standards page would take 4 hours to have all its elements inserted (elements, not even nodes). And biggest concerns about innerHTML are that it is an XSS vector, and it will erase the content, possibly leading to worth performances than appendChild depending on the operation.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for this refreshing write-up. I am completely with you: it is not about pleasing the cool kids but about writing efficient code that is easy to read and maintain. And something that suits the task at hand. There is no "one size fits all".

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much everything regarding Jquery is consider outdated, that's why sites such as Github and frameworks as Bootstrap are droping Jquery use.

The non outdated will be in fact handling the DOM yourself whit `createElement()` (which Jquery does under the hood), but as you can tell it gets pretty complicated doing all that yourself

So alternatives are:

- using a web front end framework such as Angular, React or Vue
- using a modern library to handle DOM updates

Not saying Jquery is useless it still gets the job done but there are many reasons not tu use anymore, most of them comming from the fact that JS got many new feature that are now native and not having any need to re implementing with more code from Jquery